# concatenating two txt files - is there a way to do this as a merge on a column?

Tags: python, concatenation

I have two text files that I am able to concatenate just fine. f1 is tokens and counts (2 cols) and f2 is tokens and vectors (1+n cols where n=number of vectors). The token always appears in the first col of each file.

```
#concatenate these two txt files into a new file
with open('s1_5w10f_vocab.txt')as f1, open('s1_5w10f_vectors.txt') as f2, open('/Users/dlhoffman/5w10f.txt', 'w') as f3:
    for x,y in zip(f1,f2):
        f3.write(x.strip() + " " + y.strip() + '\n')
```

Here's what a row of the new concatenated file looks like:

```
new 10950 new -0.272530 -0.001466 -0.283271 0.113374 -0.741011 -0.858208 -0.044069 0.787044 0.550195 -0.429844
```

I only need the token (in the example above "new") to appear once at the beginning of the row. Is there a way to concatenate these two files "by" their respective first columns so that in the new concatenated file, the "merged by" column is in only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your elements are delimited by spaces you could strip the leading token off of the second row in the following way.

```
with open('s1_5w10f_vocab.txt')as f1, open('s1_5w10f_vectors.txt') as f2, open('/Users/dlhoffman/5w10f.txt', 'w') as f3:
for x,y in zip(f1,f2):
    f3.write(x.strip() + " " + y[y.index(' '):].strip() + '\n')
```

This creates a substring of the second string after the first space that it finds and then calls strip() on that.

Happy coding!